# Find x,y indices corresponding to particular z value, built in function?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Say I have a matrix with `NY` row and `NX` columns

```
a(NY,NX)
```

Say for some ints `i`,`j`,

```
a(i,j) = value
```

Is there a built in function in MATLAB that give me the set A := {all (i,j) such that value = a(i,j)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html) with two outputs:

```
[ii jj] = find(A==value);
```

Example:

```
>> A = [ 1 2 3;
         3 2 1;
         2 1 0];
>> value = 3;
>> [ii jj] = find(A==value)
ii =
     2
     1
jj =
     1
     3
```

Note that the results are ordered first by column, then by row.